# Can we use Apple Pay for Customer to Customer application?

Tags: ios, payment, applepay

I am new to Apple Pay. We need to develop an application in which we need to pay from Customer to Customer. I have checked out official documentation of ApplePay for payment from the documents given on below link.

https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/

They have mentioned that customer can pay to merchant for Service or goods.

But if we need to accept make payment one customer to other customer then it is possible or not? If it is possible then how can we accept it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think it will work, the devices are not made to receive paiements, only to ask banks authorization to issue them.

Comment: Yes, so it means payment can be made to only one person from application that is merchant, right?

Comment: It has to be merchant with an adapted paiement terminal I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Pay can be used to make any payment into a merchant's account, using one of the payment providers that Apple Pay supports. Currently Apple Pay supports payments using Braintree, Stripe and others (see their web page). It's up to you what you do with the money once you receive it, you could transfer it to another user, but not using Apple Pay.

You'd want to use a payment provider that supports customer to customer payments, like Paypal.